# "Indenting" document structure

Tags: koma-script

I have 4 single documents here, each of which use sections as highest level of structure

Now I want to combine them into one scrartcl. I input them into my new document with the 'import' package, which works fine so far.

The issue I have now, is, I want to have each of the original documents as a section, therefor "indenting" all the structures inside the imported documents by one (section -> subsection, subsection -> subsubsection etc.) to keep the overall structure intact.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Regards,

Norman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redifine the sectioning commands:

```
 \let\chapter\section
 \let\section\subsection
 \let\subsection\subsubsection
 \let\subsubsection\paragraph
 \let\paragraph\relax
```

and enter the four new sections as `\chapter`s.

Comment: You are welcome. You might consider marking it as accepted.